# Massaging the DOM with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I know manipulating the DOM goes against the rules of Angular but in this case, am having do transverse the DOM to modify a sibling node.

In jQuery you can do something like this:

***$(this).parent().addClass('.loading');***

While in Angular you would do something like this:

***angular.element(this).parent().addClass('.loading');***

Certainly this doesn't work because there is no parent() method or addClass() method support on the API.

Which brings me to the question, how else can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use jQuery with Angularjs.

Comment: We need to know exactly what you're trying to do. The ng-class directive is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Angular elements are wrapped with **jqLite** by default (Angular's own jQuery implementation). If you have added jQuery to your project, then elements are wrapped with full jQuery.

Here's a list of methods available with jQuery lite http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element

As you can see, you have access to `parent()` and `addClass()` So you get a lot of DOM manipulation power w/o adding jQuery as a dependency.

-*-

It's perfectly fine to manipulate the DOM with angular, the best practice is to do it from directives, here's a little example of an element having access to the parent element

HTML

```
<div ng-app='app'>
    <div id="someparent">
        <div my-directive>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);


app.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes){
            console.log(element.parent().attr('id'));  // "someparent"
            element.parent().addClass('loading');    // adding loading class to parent
        }
    };
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jaimem/Efyv4/1/

Of course when building your app you might want to have directives manipulating only elements within itself.

-*-

Also, as Mark mentions, you can use angular's existing directives such as `ngClass` instead of creating your own. It's not clear what you want to achieve, but I recommend looking at [ngCloak](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angCloak).

Answer (score 3):

In jQuery, we often have some event trigger, then from the element that triggered the event, we traverse the DOM to find some other element which is then manipulated.  E.g.,  your example:

```
// some event causes this code to execute:
$(this).parent().addClass('.loading');
```

In AngularJS, we declare where the manipulation points are in HTML first (e.g., ng-class as @blesh suggests), then events modify $scope properties, and Angular does the DOM manipulation automagically for us.  E.g.:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-class="loadingClass">parent
   <a ng-click="loadingClass='loading'">child</a>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    // if you want some other class initially, uncomment next line:
    // $scope.loadingClass = 'notLoading';
}​
```

Above, clicking the "child" link modifies $scope.loadingClass.  Angular will notice the change and apply the new class to the parent div.

For more complicated manipulations, a custom directive like @jm- shows would be required.

jQuery: events drive DOM traversal and DOM manipulation code (imperative).
Angular: events modify $scope and the magic happens (on our declarative HTML).