# Should use angular.element or $?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

angular.element and $ basically refer to the same thing. In angularjs, which one is best practice of doing and have better performance?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337556/massaging-the-dom-with-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

If you ask about best practice, it should be use `angular.element` instead. Because Angular use jQLite by default in the `angular.element` object, but if you include jQuery, it will become full jQuery, not jQLite. So it provide more safety to our code.

Here is the [official reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).